# Trying to Create a dynamic button with an image but having some trouble fetching the image from my database

Tags: c#, wpf, button

okay I have a column(Image)[Blob] in my database, where I should fetch the Image for my dynamically created button. I want to set each button with their corresponding Image.

I tried a code suggested and It's not working please  take a look.

```
            conn.Open();

            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT GarmentName FROM tblthesis", conn))
            {
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                MainWindow mainWin = new MainWindow();

                    //button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);
                    foreach (DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        var imageBuffer = (byte[])dataRow["Image"];
                        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
                        {
                            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                            bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                            bitmapImage.EndInit();
                        }

                        Button button = new Button();
                        button.Content = dataRow[0].ToString();
                        button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(7, 7, 7, 7);
                        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                        button.Width = 185;
                        button.Height = 200;
                        button.Background = new ImageBrush(bitmapImage);
                        mainWin.sp.Children.Add(button);
```

This is how I saved my Image

```
             try
        {
            if (imageName != "")
            {
                //Initialize a file stream to read the image file
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                //Initialize a byte array with size of stream
                byte[] imgByteArr = new byte[fs.Length];

                //Read data from the file stream and put into the byte array
                fs.Read(imgByteArr, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

                //Close a file stream
                fs.Close();

                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string sql = "insert into tblthesis(GarmentType,GarmentName,Image) values('" + txtType.Text + "','" + txtname.Text + "',@img)";
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
                    {
                        //Pass byte array into database
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("img", imgByteArr));
                        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (result == 1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Image added successfully.");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

and this is how i retrieved my image

```
   ListBoxItem lb = (lbpics.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            ds = new DataSet();

            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT Image FROM tblthesis where GarmentName = '" + lb.Content.ToString() + "'", conn))
            {
                 adapter.Fill(ds);

        byte[] data = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]; 

        MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(); 

        strm.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 

        strm.Position = 0;            
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm); 
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(); 
        bi.BeginInit(); 
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  
        bi.StreamSource = ms; 
        bi.EndInit(); 
        image2.Source = bi;

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what "not working" means exactly. What exact problem do you encounter? How is the non-working code in the first code block related to the (working?) code in the third block? If the third block works, why don't you just use `byte[] data = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];` from there?

Comment: Or just `var imageBuffer = (byte[])dataRow[0];`

Comment: I just used the 2nd and 3rd block of code as a reference, I only have problem in the first block, You see, Without the code 

<code>var imageBuffer = (byte[])dataRow["Image"]</code> up to 
<code>bitmapImage.EndInit();</code>

                        
my code is working fine, but without the image background of my button.
I just want to have the image background of my button depending on what was in my column(Image).

Comment: @ is missing for parameter.  cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@img", imgByteArr)); And you're weak against SQL injection attack because of dynamic query.

Comment: What I want is, when i saved a data, I want to automatically create a dynamic button which has the background property of the image that I saved with it.

Comment: When it's working fine without that code, how does it behave *with* it? We still don't know anything about any error that occurs on your side. Since we have no glass balls to read, we can't help you. And please do not write <code> tags in comments. They don't work. Use reverse single quotes.

Comment: You're only making dataset with GarmentName because you selected it only. Syntax should be SELECT GarmentName, Image FROM tblthesis

Comment: @Kay Lee yoou are a lifesaver!